# Unable to comment on certain questions

Tags: discussion, support, design, reputation, comments

On the iPhone app, when reading a question that does not have any comments from other users one is unable to add a comment.

There is only the option to "add an answer".

For example, on this question: [Several items disabled on iPhone](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/221633/162909), I am only able to see this:

[image: No "comment button"?]

However, occasionally, if there is a question that already has a comment on it, I am able to add a comment. I am unable to find an example at the moment.

Is this due to an unknown site mechanic or due to a lack of sufficient rep?

**EDIT:** I found an example of the "Add Comment" button appearing:

[image: Here it is]

Strangely, it appeared on my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's actually how the site works:

- You need a reputation of 50 (see https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/privileges) to be able to comment on every post.
- You can always comment on your own posts

Comment: I seeeee. So that's what the "Comment Everywhere" privilege was about. I must've gotten confused between my U&L profile and the Ask Different one.